# How to loop a jquery.cycle() slideshow twice

Tags: jquery, cycle

I am using jquery.cycle() with no problems>

However, my boss wants me to loop through the slides twice and then stop on the first slide.

I can see with autostop one can loop once. But how can one specify for the slideshow to loop twice?

Can it be done?

Comment: Please mark the answer that best helped you by clicking the checkmark that is next to it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `autostopCount`: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html

```
autostop:0,     // true to end slideshow after X transitions (where X == slide count) 
autostopCount: 0,     // number of transitions (optionally used with autostop to define X)
```

Another option, if that doesn't work the way I think it does:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var index = 1;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        $('#slideshow').cycle('next');
        index++;
        if(index == cycleLength*2) {
            clearInterval(interval);    
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

You'll have to supply `cycleLength` yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Little Big Bot,

You can pause the cycle by checking the 'after' event based on the desired logic

```
var numberOfImages = 3;var counter=0;
after: function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag)   {
    counter++;
    if(counter > numberOfImages*2) 
        $('#slideshow').cycle('pause');
}
```

Comment: I want to thank everyone!. I'm trying to accept the answers. I always have a hard time with that :-( Bt (

Answer (score 2):

To expound on previous answers, the actual code to stop on the first slide after X transitions http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/LKUyg/:

```
var numberReptitions = 2;

$('#slideshow').cycle(
    {
        autostop:1,     // true to end slideshow after X transitions (where X == slide count) 
        autostopCount: ($('#slideshow').children().length*numberReptitions)+1
});​
```